# How to give an antipaladin remove disease, for... reasons

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, disease, antipaladin

I have an aspiring antipaladin of Urgathoa, may she stay forever gluttonous, and when reading through The Pallid Princess's section in *Inner Sea Gods* I noticed how in the variant spellcasting section it has,

> Priests who cast *[remove disease](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/remove-disease/)* may draw disease into themselves as they heal their targets; they become carriers without suffering ill effects.

Which, paired with the antipaladin's [Plague Bringer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/alternate-classes/antipaladin/#TOC-Plague-Bringer-Ex-) ability, would allow for further gathering of diseases.

Also, it wouldn't hurt party relations if an antipaladin could remove the diseases that his party members accidentally catch when hanging around him.

So is it possible for an antipaladin to gain access to *[remove disease](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/remove-disease/)* aside from having a library of scrolls for the spell? Possibly a piece of equipment of some kind?

Comment: Are you looking for a Paizo-published item/ability? If not, is there a reason that the magic item crafting rules are insufficient to make a "Spell in a Can" item for the character to use?

Comment: As an antipaladin, do you qualify as a priest?  If not, that variant spellcasting may not be available to you.

Comment: @BenBarden if you turn that into a question, I would gladly answer it.

Comment: @ShadowKras I don't care personally, but it seems pertinent to the question here.  The question seems to assume that it will work.  If it doesn't, the entire idea falls apart.  If it does work, not an issue.

Comment: @minnmass I was wondering if there was something that was already published before I turned to just crafting something.

Comment: @BenBarden Seeing as the term priest is rather nebulous, I interpreted it as a religious person of Urgathoa.

Comment: It has a proper definition under each deity in the Inner Sea Gods.

Comment: @ShadowKras The "Priest's Role" section?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Races

[Samsarans](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-samsaran/) with the racial trait **Mystic Past Life** could add [Remove Disease](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/remove-disease) to their spell list. You would get to pick 1 plus your Charisma modifier spells from any of the classes allowed to cast the spell and add to your class spell list.

### Prestige Classes

The [Pathfinder Savant](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/prestige-classes/other-paizo/a-b/arcane-savant/) allows you to pick spells from any other class spell list, but they are treated as one spell level higher for your character. This means that [Remove Disease](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/remove-disease) would become a 4th level anti-paladin spell. Note that the requirements of the class and the loss of one spellcasting level would make this a bad choice for your character, but it's a choice.

### Magic Items

The [Plague Mask](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/m-p/mask-plague/) (7,500 gp) allows the wearer to cast [Remove Disease](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/remove-disease) once per day. This is possibly the easiest way to infect your character with all sort of diseases.